# Display reverse order of multi-values in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select library to allow users to select multiple options from a dropdown list.  The input field is limited in space and therefor I have modified the code to show only one selected option and the another label that shows a count of the total selected.
However, the one selected option that I want to display should be the last selected option, not the first.

For example, in the screenshot below, I have selected "Ocean" first and "Orange" last (ie: "Orange" is the most recent selected option).  [image]
I therefor want to display the most recent selected option, "Orange", in the input (I believe it is called ValueContainer) field.

How can I go about achieving this?

Below is a minimum working example of what i currently have implemented:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-multivalue-order-64tylo?file=/example.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
const MultiValue = ({ index, getValue, ...props }) => {
  const maxToShow = 1;
  const overflow = getValue()
    .slice(0, -maxToShow)
    .map((x) => x.label);

  return index === getValue().length-maxToShow ? ( //This is where you show the last value instead of the first
    <components.MultiValue {...props} />
  ) : index === maxToShow ? (
    <MoreSelectedBadge items={overflow} />
  ) : null;
};
```

[Working example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-multivalue-order-forked-mcle9x)

Comment: Hi mTv, thank you this works!  It did however introduced another issue in terms of the pill display while the input field is in focus, but its ok for now.  I will investigate and revert if I am unable to resolve.  Thanks again